# How to pass WebdriverIO's browser object to SeleniumWebDriverHarnessEnvironment for harness loader(@angular/cdk/testing)

Tags: angular, webdriver, webdriver-io, angular-cdk

I have just started using the WebdriverIO since Protractor is getting deprecated.

Previously we have used Angular's Component Harness for our tests. When we tried to migrate the existing tests, we found the Angular team implemented '@angular/cdk/testing/selenium-webdriver' as a replacement for the Protractor-harness environment.

I got a blocker now when I pass the WebdriverIO browser's object to SeleniumWebDriverHarnessEnvironment. Could someone help me on finding a solution?

```
import { SeleniumWebDriverHarnessEnvironment } from "@angular/cdk/testing/selenium-webdriver";
const harnessLoader: HarnessLoader = SeleniumWebDriverHarnessEnvironment.loader(driver);
```

I am getting an error as

```
'TypeError: root(...).findElements is not a function'.
at .\src\cdk\testing\selenium-webdriver\selenium-web-driver-harness-environment.ts:43:14
```

Comment: Better to open an issue with protractor or webdriver-io repos as well.

Comment: did you make any progress with this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found that upgrading to `Angular 13` helped.

I found some e2e test code written by the Angular team which was on version `13`